# Post file larger then 64KB to WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm using Postman to POST a binary file larger then 64KB to a WebApi controller.

When reading the Stream I receive the first 64KB of data and everything larger is filled with empty bytes.

Can't figure out what I've missed.

Edit: Also I've tried IIS and IIS Express.

### Config

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="DocumentService.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="2097152" />
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <applicationSettings>
    <DocumentService.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="datafolder" serializeAs="String">
        <value>c:\temp\</value>
      </setting>
    </DocumentService.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

### Code

```
[Route("api/documents/{company}/{type}/{id}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(string company, string type, string id)
{

    string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Properties.Settings.Default.datafolder, company, type, id);
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
    {
        return BadRequest($"File {path} already exists");
    }

    var data = Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
    data.Position = 0;
    var buffer = new Byte[data.Length];
    // <-- data.length corresponds with the length of the file. 
    //     the first 64KB are filled with data the rest are empty bytes
    await data.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, (int)data.Length);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, buffer);

    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: I've added the configuration in my question with the maxRequestLength and requestLimit as in the answer you've linked. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, I missed it, sorry.

Comment: No worries, it's the first thing I've tried.

Comment: Have you tried reading file from request using HttpPostedFile type? If not give a try.       var req = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            if (req.Files.Count < 1 )
            {
                //return BadRequest
            }
            List<HttpPostedFile> files= new List<HttpPostedFile>(); 
            req.Files.GetKey(i) == "Filename";

Comment: Since you have specified - maxAllowedContentLength & maxRequestLength in configs. I feel there is no issue with configs.

Comment: @kaarthickraman your code didn't work however it send me on the right track. I'm using form-data now instead of sending a raw file and this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kaarthickraman helped getting me on the right track.

I've been testing with Postman using the `binary` option instead of the `form-data` option.
This works! Although I still don't understand why the binary option **doesn't** work.

Also a code change:

```
[Route("api/documents/{company}/{type}/{id}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(string company, string type, string id)
{

    string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Properties.Settings.Default.datafolder, company, type, id);
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
    {
            return BadRequest($"File {path} already exists");
    }

    HttpRequest req = HttpContext.Current.Request;
    if (req.Files.Count != 1)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    HttpPostedFile file = req.Files[0];
    byte[] buffer = new Byte[file.InputStream.Length];
    await file.InputStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, (int)file.InputStream.Length);
    File.WriteAllBytes(path, buffer);

    return Ok();
}
```

[image: postman]

Comment: If you upload multiple files,Your code will throw error here -  in HttpPostedFile file = req.Files[0];

Comment: And this will work . List<HttpPostedFile> files= new List<HttpPostedFile>();                                   for (int i = 0; i < req.Files.Count; i++)
            {  files.Add(req.Files.GetKey(i) == "file"); }